# How to remove the left border on a button in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to make a custom button in jetpack Compose which starts on the left without a Border, but keeps the BorderStroke on all other sides. Like so:

[image]

However the only thing I manage to produce is this button:

[image]

My code for the button:

```
@Composable
fun StandardButton(modifier: Modifier, onClicked: () -> Unit) {
    OutlinedButton(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(70.dp)
        .padding(PaddingValues(end = 50.dp)),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Black),
        border = BorderStroke(6.dp, Color.Blue),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 0.dp, topEnd = 50.dp, bottomEnd = 50.dp),
        onClick = onClicked) {
        Text(text = "Button")
    }
}
```

I tried adding a drawbehind modifier to draw the stroke myself:

```
fun Modifier.topBorder(strokeWidth: Dp, color: Color, cornerRadiusDp: Dp) = composed(
    factory = {
        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }
        val cornerRadiusPx = density.run { cornerRadiusDp.toPx() }

        Modifier.drawBehind {
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height

            drawLine(
                color = color,
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = height),
                end = Offset(x = 0f, y = cornerRadiusPx),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
            )

            drawArc(
                color = color,
                startAngle = 180f,
                sweepAngle = 90f,
                useCenter = false,
                topLeft = Offset.Zero,
                size = Size(cornerRadiusPx * 2, cornerRadiusPx * 2),
                style = Stroke(width = strokeWidthPx)
            )

            drawLine(
                color = color,
                start = Offset(x = cornerRadiusPx, y = 0f),
                end = Offset(x = width - cornerRadiusPx, y = 0f),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
            )

            drawArc(
                color = color,
                startAngle = 270f,
                sweepAngle = 90f,
                useCenter = false,
                topLeft = Offset(x = width - cornerRadiusPx * 2, y = 0f),
                size = Size(cornerRadiusPx * 2, cornerRadiusPx * 2),
                style = Stroke(width = strokeWidthPx)
            )

            drawLine(
                color = color,
                start = Offset(x = width, y = height),
                end = Offset(x = width, y = cornerRadiusPx),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
            )
        }
    }
)

fun Modifier.bottomBorder(strokeWidth: Dp, color: Color, cornerRadiusDp: Dp) = composed(
    factory = {
        val density = LocalDensity.current
        val strokeWidthPx = density.run { strokeWidth.toPx() }
        val cornerRadiusPx = density.run { cornerRadiusDp.toPx() }

        Modifier.drawBehind {
            val width = size.width
            val height = size.height

            drawLine(
                color = color,
                start = Offset(x = 0f, y = 0f),
                end = Offset(x = 0f, y = height-cornerRadiusPx),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
            )

            drawArc(
                color = color,
                startAngle = 90f,
                sweepAngle = 90f,
                useCenter = false,
                topLeft = Offset(x = 0f, y = height - cornerRadiusPx * 2),
                size = Size(cornerRadiusPx * 2, cornerRadiusPx * 2),
                style = Stroke(width = strokeWidthPx)
            )

            drawLine(
                color = color,
                start = Offset(x = cornerRadiusPx, y = height),
                end = Offset(x = width - cornerRadiusPx, y = height),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
            )

            drawArc(
                color = color,
                startAngle = 0f,
                sweepAngle = 90f,
                useCenter = false,
                topLeft = Offset(x = width - cornerRadiusPx * 2, y = height - cornerRadiusPx * 2),
                size = Size(cornerRadiusPx * 2, cornerRadiusPx * 2),
                style = Stroke(width = strokeWidthPx)
            )

            drawLine(
                color = color,
                start = Offset(x = width, y = 0f),
                end = Offset(x = width, y = height - cornerRadiusPx),
                strokeWidth = strokeWidthPx
            )
        }
    }
)
```

Usage:

```
@Composable
fun StandardButton(modifier: Modifier, onClicked: () -> Unit) {
    OutlinedButton(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(70.dp)
        .padding(PaddingValues(end = 50.dp))
        .topBorder(6.dp, Color.White, 50.dp)
        .bottomBorder(6.dp, Color.White, 50.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(containerColor = Color.Black),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(topStart = 0.dp, topEnd = 50.dp, bottomEnd = 50.dp),
        onClick = onClicked) {
        Text(text = "Button")
    }
}
```

Which resulted in this:

[image]

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick and dirty way would be to add a negative x-axis offset to the button:

```kotlin
    modifier = Modifier
                  .offset(x = -16.dp)
                  ...
```

This will hide the left portion of the button.

Comment: I don't know how I didn't think of this. Thank you!

Comment: There is no straight forward solution for this until I found this answer and creating custom modifier to just remove boarder is overkill in my opinion.